# Matlab: How to sort data for each row/column, loop or formula?

Tags: matlab, loops

This is how the data looks like:

```
20.00 32.00 33.00 10.00 23.00 ......

12.00 22.00 21.00 10.00 32.00 ......

10.00 21.00 21.00 34.00 12.00 ......

......
```

I would like to sort row(1), row(2)....row(n) separately. Should I write a loop or does any formula work here? Look for a solution, Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you've got the data in a Matlab matrix then the sort function will do the trick:

```
A = [1,3,2
     4,1,3]
```

The sort function needs the dimension to be specified - since by default it sorts the columns. Array indexing in matlab starts at 1, so the number required is 2.

```
sort(A,2) = [1,2,3
             1,3,4]
```

More info: http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/sort.html

Answer (score 1):

In MATLAB `sort` function, you can specify the dimension along which to sort. If you're surting along the *rows*, use dimension 2 (columns are dimension 1).

```
sort( data , 2 );
```

Answer (score 0):

The default behavior for sort(X) where X is a matrix is to sort each column individually.  If you would like to sort the rows, you can use sort(x,2) or sort(x').